# How to compute the Chern number of a quantum dot (zero-dimensional topological insulator) in AI class?

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, topological-insulators

Looking at the periodic table of topological insulators, the AI class (only time reversal symmetry is preserved) has a $\mathbb{Z}$ invariant for zero-dimensional topological insulators. In the review by Chiu et al (2016) "Classification of topological quantum matter with symmetries," this invariant is identified as a Chern number. It is well-established that the Chern number is related to the integral of the Berry curvature over the Brillouin zone summed over the occupied bands. In formulas, if $|u_{n,\mathbf{k}} \rangle$ is the $n$th Bloch eigenfunction at wave vector $\mathbf{k}$, the Berry curvature is $\langle u_{n,\mathbf{k}} | \nabla_{\mathbf{k}} u_{n,\mathbf{k}} \rangle$.

I have two questions:

1. How can this formula be adapted for the zero-dimensional case where the Brillouin zone is a point?
2. What is the physical (or mathematical) meaning of the Chern number in the zero-dimensional case? For the finite dimensional case, I understand that the Chern number is related to the homotopy group of a Grassmanian. This physically represents an obstruction in defining a globally continuous choice of Bloch eigenfunction. Do such interpretations still hold for the zero-dimensional case?

Problem background: I want to compute mirror Chern numbers of a reflection-symmetric 1D system in class AI. The same paper mentions that this can be done by computing the Chern numbers of an effective 0D system obtained by considering the 1D system at the specific wave vectors $0$ and $\pi$.